# How do you add help to buttons?

Tags: button, helptext

I want add help text to every button. How do I do it?

Comment: I want help help text to custom buttons.

Comment: Can you please share some more info? Is it custom buttons inside a visualforce page?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is only possible in visualforce pages by setting the title attribute in a commandButton tag.

I don't think that there is a way to set this for buttons on standard page layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a help text on a field/button is possible by visualforce. Use the below code it'll surely help you.

Style code

---

```
<style>
        .vfHelpText a            {position:relative;}
        .vfHelpText a span       {display: none;}
        .vfHelpText a:hover span {display: block;
                                  position:absolute;
                                  top:1.25em;
                                  padding:2px 5px;
                                  left:-15em; width:15em;
                                  z-index:100;
                                  border:1px solid orange;
                                  background-color:#FEFDB9;
                                  color:black;
                                 }
    </style>

Text Code // add it this code after your button component
***********************************************************

 <span class="vfHelpText">
        <a>
            <img src="/s.gif" alt="" class="helpOrb" />
            <span>{!helpText}</span>
        </a>
    </span>
```